# How to delete a gem so that I don't need to prepend bundle exec for rails commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

If I try to run tests I get

Gem::LoadError: You have already activated jruby-openssl 0.9.5, but your Gemfile requires jruby-openssl 0.8.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

I can do as indicated and prepend `bundle exec` to get around this.
This is happening because I have a *newer* version of the gem in another project.

However I am no longer using the other application with the newer version of the gem, so I was wondering:

How can I actually remove the newer version so I don't have to bundle exec before my rails commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a gem (or a specific version of a gem) by running

```
gem uninstall <gem_name>
```

If there's multiple versions then a prompt will ask which version to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gem uninstall` with the `-v` switch to specify a version to uninstall:

```
gem uninstall jruby-openssl -v 0.9.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS and shell, you could create an alias or function for the command (I’m guessing this is using Rake).

For example I have this in my `.bashrc`

```bash
function bake {
  bundle exec rake "$@"
}
```

So now I can type `bake whatever` and the command that is run is `bundle exec rake whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are 'polluting' the global gemset using it for different projects.

A good way to isolate gemsets is to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). Once installed, you can create a file per project named `.ruby-version` with a single line on it that identifies the gemset with the syntax `<ruby version>@<your project>`. From the console:

```
$> echo "2.1@myproject" > .ruby-version
$> cd .
```

This will create a gemset for your project and everytime you enter the root directory, the gemset will be specific to this project. Then you could have different gem versions for different projects and run `rake` (or any other command) just fine without messing dependencies.

Comment: It might also happen if you've just changed some gems or upgraded some gems in your current project.